# Сортировка двумерного массива по убыванию первых элементов

Tags: c, массивы

Вместо сортировки строк сортирует значения в строке. В чём проблема?

`1 7 5 3
5 4 2 0
2 3 9 8
4 1 3 2`

Должно вывести:

`5 4 2 0
4 1 3 2
2 3 9 8
1 7 5 3`

```
for(k=0; k<=(n*n); k++)
    {
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
           for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
            {
              if(a[i*n + j]<a[i*n + (j+1)])
               {
                 t=a[i*n + j];
                 a[i*n + j]=a[i*n + (j+1)];
                 a[i*n + (j+1)]=t;
               }
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Вы могли бы сначала пояснить, что вы пытаетесь сделать?!

Comment: И не ясно, то ли вам самому надо написать сортировку (и какой использовать метод), то ли можно использовать стандартную сортировку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот демонстрационная программа, состоящая из двух кодовых блоков. В первом кодовом блоке показывается, как можно отсортировать массив, используя стандартную функцию `qsort`, а во втором кодовом блоке массив сортируется методом выборки.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int cmp( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    int x = *( int * )p1;
    int y = *( int * )p2;

    return ( y > x ) - ( x > y );
}

#define N   4

int main( void )
{
{    
    int a[N][N] =
    {        
        { 1, 7, 5, 3 },
        { 5, 4, 2, 0 },
        { 2, 3, 9, 8 },
        { 4, 1, 3, 2 }
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    qsort( a, N, sizeof( int[N] ), cmp );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}    

{    
    int a[N][N] =
    {        
        { 1, 7, 5, 3 },
        { 5, 4, 2, 0 },
        { 2, 3, 9, 8 },
        { 4, 1, 3, 2 }
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t max = i;
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++ )
        {
            if ( a[max][0] < a[j][0] ) max = j;
        }

        if ( max != i )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
            {
                int tmp = a[max][j];
                a[max][j] = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}    
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
1 7 5 3 
5 4 2 0 
2 3 9 8 
4 1 3 2 

5 4 2 0 
4 1 3 2 
2 3 9 8 
1 7 5 3 

1 7 5 3 
5 4 2 0 
2 3 9 8 
4 1 3 2 

5 4 2 0 
4 1 3 2 
2 3 9 8 
1 7 5 3
```

Comment: @Дмитрий Вы можете использовать тип int. size_t - это стандартное определение имени типа для некоторого беззнакового целого типа.  Обычно он определяется как typedef unsigned long size_t;. Просто индексация массивов начинается с 0, то есть имеет неотрицательные значения, то я и выбрал стандартный беззнаковый целочисленный тип для индексов. Также оператор sizeof имеет тип возвращаемого значения size_t

Comment: Спасибо, понял!
Вот ещё проблема: Измен. Ваш код для того, что бы массив сорт. по возраст. первых элементов колонки, но работает оно через раз. Не пойму в чём закономерность. Прошу прощение за колбасный код:(
`for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        max2 = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (b[0][max2] > b[0][j])
            max2 = j;
        }

        if ( max2 != j )
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++ )
            {
                int tmp2 = b[i][max2];
                b[i][max2] = b[i][j];
                b[i][j] = tmp2;
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @Дмитрий Если вы хотите сортировать по возрастанию, то лучше использовать имя переменной min вместо max2. У вас в коде опечатка. В предложении с if должна быть переменная i, а не j. if ( min != i ) ...

Comment: Теперь вместо нерабочей сортировки ещё и все элементы массива непонятным образом меняются местами :)

Comment: @Дмитрий У вас имеется еще одна опечатка. В условии должно быть if ( b[j][0] < b[min][0] ). То есть вы порядок индексов напутали.

Comment: Второй цикл должен быть такой же? `for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)`

Comment: @Дмитрий Все, как в моем ответе. Только в if другое сравнение.

Comment: Если сделать всё так же, элементы переставляются в произвольном порядке: https://goo.gl/ioC9Q6

Comment: @Дмитрий Все правильно: сортирует строки по возрастанию первых элементов каждой строки. А вы что хотите? Сортировать колонки?

Comment: "Измен. Ваш код для того, что бы массив сорт. по возраст. первых элементов колонки" Час назад написал)

Comment: @Дмитрий Вот сортировка по колонкам по возрастанию певого элемента колонок     for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t min = i;
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++ )
        {
            if ( a[0][j] < a[0][min] ) min = j;
        }

        if ( min != i )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
            {
                int tmp = a[j][min];
                a[j][min] = a[j][i];
                a[j][i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Всё так просто... А я там огородов нагородил.
Ещё раз большое спасибо!

Comment: @Дмитрий Не за что.:)